# Setup Development Environment For Windows Embedded Compac

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-embedded-compact

Hi guys I am trying to develop for a Windows Embedded Compact edition 2013 using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10. But I have not been able to.

I have installed the Application Builder and still could not find a template in Visual Studio 2013.

Please can anyone help.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 should be a better setup.

Comment: I have to continue reverse engineer a project and I have tried using it to open the solution, but I get this solution was created using a a latest version

Comment: Manually downgrade the solution and project files, or simply create new ones in VS2008 and cut/paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Application Builder is just one of the pieces.

Another piece is the SDK that was developed for the target platform.  This includes hardware components and drivers (BSP) and software components (what Windows Embedded Compact 2013) options have been installed.  Hopefully this has been written for you.

If the SDK hasn't been developed or it needs other drivers or Windows components to be loaded for your project, you will need to install other Windows Embedded Compact 2013 tools.